# Hinge Rod system but the rod is massless

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

> Problem: A massless rod of length $L$ has one of its ends attached to a hinge. A bead of mass $m$  is placed at the mid point of the rod. Find the equation of trajectory of the bead.

My answer : Here , the bead will be in free fall and let's assume the hinge to be the origin $O(0,0)$ . It is fairly obvious that it will make some general angle ,say, $\theta$ below the origin . The coordinates of the bead at that instant will be $\left(\frac{L}{2},\frac{L}{2}\tan\theta\right)$ . Therefore , the equation of trajectory  is turning out to be $x^2+y^2=\frac{L^2}{4}\sec^2 \theta$ for $\theta\in\left[0,-\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ which is of the form $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=f(\theta)$ .

I am confused as to what curve it represents and is it even possible? Also , i would be very grateful if someone could point out my mistake .